# Capybara Test for n buttons dependant on number of Records in a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Is it possible to write an integration test which checks that *N* buttons have appeared on a page where *N* is the number of Records in a Model?

I have a model *suite* and a controller *suites_controller*. The *suites_controller* index action retrieves all the records in the *suite* model

```
def index
    @suites = Suite.all
end
```

In my *views/suites/index.html.erb* I generate a button for each suite

```
<% @suites.each do |suite| %>
    <%= submit_tag suite.name, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Capybara + Rspec for integration and use case tests but can't for the life of me think how I would test that the correct number of buttons have appeared in the view. I have attempted to do

```
...

# more spec above which visits '/suites'

it "displays all available suites" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:suite, name:'Suite 1')
    FactoryGirl.create(:suite, name:'Suite 2')

    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Suite 1')
    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Suite 2')
end

...
```

but I get the error

```
1) creating a new test end to end user logs in user clicks the new test button displays all available suites
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Suite 1')
   expected #has_selector?(:link_or_button, "Suite 1") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/integration/new_test_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something totally obvious or am approaching it the wrong way.

Any ideas how I could test this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's definitely missing is your test case isn't navigating to a given page. If your suites are displaying from a `SuitesController`, for instance, then you should use the [Capybara `visit` helper](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master#Navigating) to navigate to that page:

```
it "displays all available suites" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:suite, name:'Suite 1')
    FactoryGirl.create(:suite, name:'Suite 2')

    visit '/suites'

    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Suite 1')
    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Suite 2')
end
```

Comment: Apologies, I only included the part of the test which was testing the view. My entire spec does navigate to the '/suites' page meaning at this point the test is on '/suites', I'l update the question

Comment: I'm not convinced by the updates. If you visit the `/suites` page, *then* create the new ones, it won't magically update that page. If you have no suites created when visited, then your test will fail. Or if your test case is doing something more complex, then the example should show a lot more detail.

Comment: Thanks @Alex P , I was creating the entries after visiting '/suites' like a numpty...I should have created the test data before I visited '/suites'. Bloody Fridays!